# Change color of currently selected field

Tags: javascript, extjs, colors, extjs4, extjs4.1

How do I change the color of the currently selected record in extjs combobox? As you can see the image below, the record Petty Cash Fund is the currently selected item on my dropdown but the highlight color is not noticeable. How do I change this for all the combobox in my application?

[image]

Comment: There is a pretty [good docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/).. you just need to look for focus(or similar keyword) event in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selected element in a combobox has the css class `x-boundlist-selected`. Just override its color in your custom css.

Or, since it is a built-in style, you could change [`$boundlist-item-selected-background-color`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.view.BoundList-css_var-S-boundlist-item-selected-background-color) in the template

Tip: Use Chrome Developper Tools